# Mobile friendly over images - lightbox

Tags: html, css, image, overlay, lightbox

Good evening, thanks for trying to help first off.

I have a 'portfolio' page with 45 images of houses I've built. They're laid out in a grid, 5 wide 9 down. Simply, when you click and expand the image in browser, it works great. However, when I view on mobile, it get's a little fishy. The image tends to stretch past the view of the screen.

My question is: how can I make the image stay in the viewport of say my mobile device instead of stretching passed the screen? I tried absolutely positioning the overlay, that didn't work.

The lightbox script i'm using: http://tympanus.net/Tutorials/CSS3Lightbox/index3.html

My portfolio page: http://www.ocalaplastering.com/portfolio.html

This would be my html heavily reduced. Multiply the "li" element times 45 and that's basically the page.

```
<body>
<div id="wrapper">
    <div id="header"></div>
    <div id="nav"></div>
    <div content>
        <ul class="lb-album">
            <li>
                <a href="#image-1">
                <img src="images/work/thumbs/1.jpg" alt="image01">
                <span>Expand</span>
                </a>
            <div class="lb-overlay" id="image-1">
                <img src="images/work/full/1.jpg" alt="image01" />
            <div>
                <a href="#image-45" class="lb-prev">Prev</a>
                <a href="#image-2" class="lb-next">Next</a>
            </div>
                <a href="#page" class="lb-close">x Close</a>
            </div>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
</body>
```

As for the CSS, this is the styles for the aforementioned elements:

```
.lb-album{
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    font-family: 'BebasNeueRegular', 'Arial Narrow', Arial, sans-serif;
}
.lb-album li{
    float: left;
    padding:0px;
    padding-right:1px;
    padding-bottom:1px;
    position: relative;
    list-style:none;
}
.lb-album li > a,
.lb-album li > a img{
    display: block;
}
.lb-album li > a{
    width: 150px;
    height: 150px;
    position: relative;
    padding: 3px;
    background: #816445;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 1px 1px 2px #fff, 1px 1px 2px rgba(158,111,86,0.3) inset;
    -moz-box-shadow: 1px 1px 2px #fff, 1px 1px 2px rgba(158,111,86,0.3) inset;
    box-shadow: 1px 1px 2px #fff, 1px 1px 2px rgba(158,111,86,0.3) inset;
    -moz-border-radius: 4px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 4px;
    border-radius: 4px 4px 4px 4px;
}
.lb-album li > a span{
    position: absolute;
    width: 150px;
    height: 150px;
    top: 3px;
    left: 3px;
    text-align: center;
    line-height: 150px;
    color: rgba(27,54,81,0.8);
    text-shadow: 0px 1px 1px rgba(255,255,255,0.6);
    font-size: 24px;
    opacity: 0;
    filter: alpha(opacity=0); /* internet explorer */
    -ms-filter:"progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(opacity=0)"; /*IE8*/
    background: rgb(241,210,194);
    background: -moz-radial-gradient(center, ellipse cover, rgba(255,255,255,0.56) 0%, rgba(241,210,194,1) 100%);
    background: -webkit-gradient(radial, center center, 0px, center center, 100%, color-stop(0%,rgba(255,255,255,0.56)), color-stop(100%,rgba(241,210,194,1)));
    background: -webkit-radial-gradient(center, ellipse cover, rgba(255,255,255,0.56) 0%,rgba(241,210,194,1) 100%);
    background: -o-radial-gradient(center, ellipse cover, rgba(255,255,255,0.56) 0%,rgba(241,210,194,1) 100%);
    background: -ms-radial-gradient(center, ellipse cover, rgba(255,255,255,0.56) 0%,rgba(241,210,194,1) 100%);
    background: radial-gradient(center, ellipse cover, rgba(255,255,255,0.56) 0%,rgba(241,210,194,1) 100%);
    -webkit-transition: opacity 0.3s linear;
    -moz-transition: opacity 0.3s linear;
    -o-transition: opacity 0.3s linear;
    -ms-transition: opacity 0.3s linear;
    transition: opacity 0.3s linear;
}
.lb-album li > a:hover span{
    opacity: 1;
    filter: alpha(opacity=99); /* internet explorer */
    -ms-filter:"progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(opacity=99)"; /*IE8*/
}
.lb-overlay{
    width: 0px;
    height: 0px;
    position: fixed;
    overflow: hidden;
    left: 0px;
    top: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    z-index: 99;
    text-align: center;
    background: rgb(241,210,194);
    background: -moz-radial-gradient(center, ellipse cover, rgba(255,255,255,0.56) 0%, rgba(241,210,194,1) 100%);
    background: -webkit-gradient(radial, center center, 0px, center center, 100%, color-stop(0%,rgba(255,255,255,0.56)), color-stop(100%,rgba(241,210,194,1)));
    background: -webkit-radial-gradient(center, ellipse cover, rgba(255,255,255,0.56) 0%,rgba(241,210,194,1) 100%);
    background: -o-radial-gradient(center, ellipse cover, rgba(255,255,255,0.56) 0%,rgba(241,210,194,1) 100%);
    background: -ms-radial-gradient(center, ellipse cover, rgba(255,255,255,0.56) 0%,rgba(241,210,194,1) 100%);
    background: radial-gradient(center, ellipse cover, rgba(255,255,255,0.56) 0%,rgba(241,210,194,1) 100%);
}
.lb-overlay > div{
    position: relative;
    color: rgba(27,54,81,0.8);
    width: 550px;
    height: 80px;
    margin: 40px auto 0px auto;
    text-shadow: 0px 1px 1px rgba(255,255,255,0.6);
}
.lb-overlay div p{
    font-size: 14px;
    text-align: left;
    float: left;
    width: 260px;
}
.lb-overlay a.lb-close{
    background: rgba(27,54,81,0.8);
    z-index: 1001;
    color: #fff;
    position: absolute;
    top: 43px;
    left: 50%;
    font-size: 15px;
    line-height: 26px;
    text-align: center;
    width: 50px;
    height: 23px;
    overflow: hidden;
    margin-left: -25px;
    opacity: 0;
    filter: alpha(opacity=0); /* internet explorer */
    -ms-filter:"progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(opacity=0)"; /*IE8*/
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 1px 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
    -moz-box-shadow: 0px 1px 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
    box-shadow: 0px 1px 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
}
.lb-overlay img{
    /* height: 100%; For Opera max-height does not seem to work */
    max-height: 100%;
    position: relative;
    opacity: 0;
    filter: alpha(opacity=0); /* internet explorer */
    -ms-filter:"progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(opacity=0)"; /*IE8*/
    -webkit-box-shadow: 1px 1px 4px rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
    -moz-box-shadow: 1px 1px 4px rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
    box-shadow: 0px 2px 7px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
    -webkit-transition: opacity 0.5s linear;
    -moz-transition: opacity 0.5s linear;
    -o-transition: opacity 0.5s linear;
    -ms-transition: opacity 0.5s linear;
    transition: opacity 0.5s linear;
}
.lb-prev, .lb-next{
    text-indent: -9000px;
    position: absolute;
    top: -32px;
    width: 24px;
    height: 25px;
    left: 50%;
    opacity: 0.8;
    filter: alpha(opacity=80); /* internet explorer */
    -ms-filter:"progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(opacity=80)"; /*IE8*/
}
.lb-prev:hover, .lb-next:hover{
    opacity: 1;
    filter: alpha(opacity=99); /* internet explorer */
    -ms-filter:"progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(opacity=99)"; /*IE8*/
}
.lb-prev{
    margin-left: -30px;
    background: transparent url(../images/arrows.png) no-repeat top left;
}
.lb-next{
    margin-left: 6px;
    background: transparent url(../images/arrows.png) no-repeat top right;
}
.lb-overlay:target {
    width: auto;
    height: auto;
    bottom: 0px;
    right: 0px;
    padding: 80px 100px 120px 100px;
}
.lb-overlay:target img,
.lb-overlay:target a.lb-close{
    opacity: 1;
    filter: alpha(opacity=99); /* internet explorer */
    -ms-filter:"progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(opacity=99)"; /*IE8*/
}
/* 
    100% Height for Opera as the max-height seems to be ignored, not optimal for large screens 
    http://bricss.net/post/11230266445/css-hack-to-target-opera 
*/
x:-o-prefocus, .lb-overlay img {
    height: 100%;
}
```

There isn't jQuery involved, so i'm assuming it will just be a very simple property to add, but I cannot figure it out.

Cheers for the help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be solved with a simple addition to your CSS on line 355 (.lb-overlay img):
Add a max-width: 100%; below the max-height:100%;

Let me know if that makes it behave how you are expecting!

Comment: That was quite easy! Thank you very much.

Comment: When i pinch the image that is the overlay version, it will zoom in, but when i try to pan it pans the actual site behind it. What do you think would help with this? Some sort of positioning?